# Where are belt 1, 2, ... in Brussels airport?

Tags: airports, brussels, airport-terminals

I checked arrival information of my flight on the official website of the airport and it states I'm arriving at "belt 2".
I checked the airport website and did a Google search, but wasn't able to find where this "belt 2" is. I only found a baggage claim named belt 2.

What does "belt 2" (or other belts) on the arrival information refer to?

Comment: Where do you see this information? It is probably a reference to baggage claim.

Comment: It's written on the arrival details page of my flight.

Comment: To me it looks like baggage claim as well, so follow the signs to the luggage reclaim and exit and you should find your flight mentioned for belt 2.

Comment: Many airport will give the luggage claim or exit (not gate) for arrivals, as this is where people coming to meet up the arriving passengers will have to go. The gate number is considered not useful (though it can be very useful for passenger with a short transit).

Comment: Which website did you use? The official airport website indicates both gate information and baggage belt information (https://www.brusselsairport.be/fr/passengers/flights/arriving/).

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the mobile website layout is stupidly designed.
The belt information really refers to the baggage claim. It's written at the top in a very visible blue box. In French language it's even more clear to me as it's called "carousel" here.
You would have to scroll down and click a mostly hidden element called "travel planner". There you can find the gate.
It's stupid as it's the first information I'd want...

Comment: Okay, but "*the* mobile website"... which website is this?

Comment: I can't remember caring what gate I arrived at (on the final flight segment, anyway) nearly as much as I cared about which carousel my baggage would be on. "Belt" is probably a poor translation.

Comment: I'm referring to the official website.